# How to read the file on a specific directory using Quasar Capacitor in Android?

Tags: android, typescript, file, capacitor, quasar-framework

I've tried reading a document from my cellphone using Quasar + Capacitor using the **Filesystem** [plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem#readdir) and Quasar's framework [API](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/developing-capacitor-apps/capacitor-api).

I've managed to come up with the following code that allows me (through Typescript) to access my files. Nonetheless when loading them in my Galaxy S2 Android phone I get the "null Object" exception as if it couldn't find the file.

I've already tried adding the file and hardcoding the route and then it gives me the "file not found" error even though the directory is the same and the file exists. I've already checked and added the permissions to the manifest so it has read capabilities yet it still can't read files in my device.

My code is the following:

```
    const loadFileData = async () => {
    if(Platform.is.electron){
      console.log('Platform running is Electron');
      console.log(fileData);
    } else if(Platform.is.nativeMobile || Platform.is.capacitor){
        console.log('Platform running is Capacitor Mobile');
        console.log(fileSelected.value);
        console.log(fileSelected.value.name);
      //Load the file. THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERRORS
      const fileData = await Filesystem.readFile({ 
        path: fileSelected.value,
        directory: Directory.Documents,
        encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
      });
      console.log('File Data:');
      console.log(fileData);
    } else {
      console.log('Platform unknown, may be web');
      return 'Data2';
    }
}
```

I printed the output and it reads the **[file File]** object but seems to not find the path.
Is there any proper way to read a selected file from my Android device? Additionally, is there a proper way to get the contents of the folder so I can select the files?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)